# Run PHP 5 with other than Apache http server?

Tags: 14.04, apache2, php

I was wondering is there optional/secondary solution for Apache http server?

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and I was messing with mail servers. Somehow I broke my Apache installation and wasn't able to fix it.

What are other alternatives to run PHP5 locally on my Ubuntu machine?
I have Node.JS http-server installed but NodeJs can run only JavaScript.

Comment: How about nginx?

Comment: Check out http://serverfault.com/questions/243297/how-do-you-install-php5-without-installing-apache-in-ubuntu

Comment: Ok. Is it proven to work? Will I bother configuring it alot or installing separate bits to make it work?

Comment: Check out https://www.nginx.com/blog/sites-using-nginx-june-2014/

Comment: Ok. This question seems like a duplicate. Once I get my hands dirty with this stuff, will remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install [nginx](https://www.nginx.com) which is an alternate http server to apache. You can then configure php5-fpm to run through nginx.

There is a great guide at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Nginx that covers installing and setup of nginx with php5 (php5-fpm)

Answer (score 1):

Well since you have asked for an alternative solution , I think the best better alternative for Apache webserver is **Nginx** if you are not about to server any dynamic webpages. Apparently I should mention an alternative mail server solution which is free and opensource is **"iRedmail"**. This can be tuned and scaled as you like and is an enterprise grade one as well.